# want to fire ext textfield focus event in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ext.net

```
    @Html.X().TextField()
        .ID("btncolor")
        .FieldLabel("Button Color")
        .SelectOnFocus(true)
```

I want to use its focus event how can i do that. actually i want to when user focus on textfield then colorpicker window open then i select color from them and then i feed the textfield with color id i.e.(#323232).

I have try so hardly but i didn't get the right thing. any clue and suggestion will be appreciable.

The color picker is like that.

```
    @Html.X().FormPanel()
        .ID("clrpkr")
        .Title("Color  Picker")
        .Disable(true)
        .BodyPadding(6)
        .Height(380).Width(350)
        .Items(@Html.X().ColorPicker().Template(t => 
            t.Html = @"<tpl for='colors'><a href='#' class='color-{.}' hidefocus='on'><em style='padding:2px;'><span style='background:#{.};height:20px; border:1px solid black;' unselectable='on'>&#160;</span><div style='font-size:10px;text-align:center;'>#{.}</div></em></a></tpl>")
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use a TextField's Focus listener.

```
@(Html.X().TextField()
    .Listeners(events => events.Focus.Handler = "console.log('The TextField has been focused');")
)
```

Also you might be interested to look at [this example](http://examples.ext.net/#/Form/TriggerField/Overview/), see the second field.